# Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу диспетчер задач на C# с WinForms по обучалке с ютуба, но почему-то выдает ошибку про отсутствие аргумента, хотя писал код 1в1, как я понимаю это из-за перегрузки, ошибку выдает в любом месте где я вызываю RefreshProcessesList, допустим когда я обрабатывал форму там уже выдало ошибку, можете помочь разобраться в чем проблема, просто только учусь и не особо понимаю как это исправить.

```
private void RefreshProcessesList(List<Process> processes, string keyword)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        double memSize = 0;

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            memSize = 0;
            PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter();
            pc.CategoryName = "Process";
            pc.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
            pc.InstanceName = p.ProcessName;

            memSize = (double)pc.NextValue() / (1000 * 1000);

            string[] row = new string[] { p.ProcessName.ToString(), Math.Round(memSize, 1).ToString() };
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(row));
            pc.Close();
            pc.Dispose();
        }
        Text = $"Запущено процессов '{keyword}': " + processes.Count.ToString();
    }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processes = new List<Process>();

        GetProcesses();

        RefreshProcessesList();
    }
```

Comment: `RefreshProcessesList(processes, "<ключевое слово>");` у вас метод принимает 2 аргумента `List<Process> processes, string keyword`, а передаете вы ему 0 `()`.

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо огромное